# Define class with class method which calls new within then calls class instance method with the same name, what pattern is this?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I am working on a project and found this kind of pattern, see the snippet I mock up below. Is this one of the design patterns that commonly used? What's the benefit coding this way? Thanks!

NOTE: arguments here could be instances of other class, not just generic values.

```
class Foo
  def self.do_something arg1, arg2
    new(arg1, arg2).do_something
  end

  def initialize arg1, arg2
    # set instance variables
    @var1 = arg1
    @var2 = arg2
  end

  def do_something
    # do something...
    return self
  end
end
```

Two examples from my project:

1. Worker class for Resque

   ```
   class MyWorkers

     @q = 'my_queue'

     def self.enqueue(arg1, arg2)
       new(arg1, arg2).enqueue
     end

     def self.perform(arg1, arg2)
       new(arg1, arg2).perform
     end

     def initialize(arg1, arg2)
       @var1 = arg1
       @var2 = arg2
     end

     def enqueue
       Resque.enqueue(self.class, @var1, @var2)
     end

     def perform
       # do something with @var1, @var2
     end
   end
   ```
2. A class to run query and return the result

   ```
   class MyFinder
     attr_reader :result

     def self.execute(params, options={})
       new(params, options).execute
     end

     def initiailize(params, options)
       @params = params || {}
       @options = options
     end

     def execute
       # run query and set the result in instance variable
       @result = SomeModel.where(params)
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Can you give me an example where you've seen this pattern?  I want to research it. @hsw

Comment: Hi @franksort , thanks for your response. The real code is so complicated with more methods in these classes, so I simplified two of them as examples. I'm about to add features but this pattern looks difficult to refactor to me (because I don't know what this pattern for).

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method), the following is an example that mirrors what you have there. The example can be found [here](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/059-issue-25-creational-design-patterns.html) which explains it, in ruby terms, and goes in-depth about it as well as other patterns.

```
class AdjacencyMatrix  
  class << self  
    def undirected(data)  
      new(data)  
    end  

    def directed(data)  
      new(data,true)  
    end  

    private :new  
  end  

  def initialize(data, directed=false)  
    #...  
  end  
end  

undirected_matrix = AdjacencyMatrix.undirected(data)   
directed_matrix   = AdjacencyMatrix.directed(data)
```